# Using pandas to add list elements together

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following array of dicts:

```
items = [ 
{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'Language': ['en',]
},
{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'Language': ['fr',]
},

{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'Language': ['en',]
},
{
    'FirstName': 'Bob',
    'Language': ['en',]
}
]
```

Which I want to group by on FirstName and add the unique languages together, like so:

```
items = [ 
{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'Language': ['en', 'fr']
},

{
    'FirstName': 'Bob',
    'Language': ['en',]
}
]
```

The SQL I would use would be:

```
SELECT FirstName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Language ORDER BY Language)
FROM items
GROUP BY FirstName
```

Using pandas, how would I combine this and do a group by on FirstName and get an array of unique languages? Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(items)
>>> df.groupby('FirstName')['Language']
      .apply(lambda x: list(set(x))) # this line is off
      .reset_index()
      .to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: Does the language key always have a single item the first `items` list?

Comment: @user2285236 no, the language could have multiple values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aggregate all with sum, `transform` values to set and then `to_dict()`

```
>>> df.groupby('FirstName').sum()["Language"].transform(set).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')

[{'FirstName': 'Bob', 'Language': {'en'}},
 {'FirstName': 'David', 'Language': {'en', 'fr'}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('FirstName').sum().applymap(lambda s: list(set(s)))
```

[applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) will apply a function to every element, mapping a list to a de-duplicated list.

```
In [185]: df = pd.DataFrame(items)

In [186]: df
Out[186]: 
  FirstName Language
0     David     [en]
1     David     [fr]
2     David     [en]
3       Bob     [en]

In [187]: df.groupby('FirstName').sum().applymap(lambda s: list(set(s)))
Out[187]: 
           Language
FirstName          
Bob            [en]
David      [en, fr]
```

Comment: Also need to be specify 'Language' somewhere (trivial in the above example, but sometimes will have additional fields).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df.groupby('FirstName')['Language']\
  .apply(lambda x: list(set(x.str[0])))\
  .reset_index().to_dict('r')
```

Output:

```
[{'FirstName': 'Bob', 'Language': ['en']},
 {'FirstName': 'David', 'Language': ['fr', 'en']}]
```

Create a set our of the first element of the list in each group.

#### Timings

```
%timeit df.groupby('FirstName').sum().applymap(lambda s: list(set(s)))
```

> 7.31 ms ± 534 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%timeit df.groupby('FirstName')['Language'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x.str[0]))).to_frame()
```

> 2.09 ms ± 207 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: @david542  Not the timing differences between applyman and apply greater than 3x faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
from more_itertools import flatten
df.groupby('FirstName')['Language'].apply(lambda x: list(set(flatten([i for i in x]))))
.reset_index()
.to_dict(orient='records')

[{'FirstName': 'Bob', 'Language': ['en']},
 {'FirstName': 'David', 'Language': ['en', 'fr']}]
```

I assume you kept getting `unhashable type: 'list'` so I simply use a list comprehension to get the value from it and then flatten it since it ended up looking like this after just a list comprehension:

```
FirstName
Bob                  [[en]]
David    [[en], [fr], [en]]
```

Comment: @RafaelC, can you explain how it doesn't answer the question? The result is what OP is looking for.

Comment: No worries. Didn't add the result originally so may have been a misunderstanding.