# Using pandas to add list of dicts together

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow-up to this question: [Using pandas to add list elements together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261076/using-pandas-to-add-list-elements-together). I would like to generalize this function to getting unique elements in an array, even if they're not of a 'hashable' type, such as a dict. Here is the input array:

```
items = [ 
{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'LastName': 'Smith',
    'Residence': [{'Place': 'X', 'Age': 22}, {'Place': 'Y', 'Age': 23}]
},

{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'LastName': 'Smith',
    'Residence': [{'Place': 'Z', 'Age': 20}]
},

{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'LastName': 'Smith',
    'Residence': [{'Place': 'Z', 'Age': 20}]
},
{
    'FirstName': 'Bob',
    'LastName': 'Jones',
    'Residence': [{'Place': 'Z', 'Age': 20}]
}
]
```

I want to add together the unique Residences (dicts) together, so the final result would be:

```
items = [ 
{
    'FirstName': 'David',
    'LastName': 'Smith',
    'Residence': [{'Place': 'X', 'Age': 22}, {'Place': 'Y', 'Age': 23}, {'Place': 'Z', 'Age': 20}]
},

{
    'FirstName': 'Bob',
    'LastName': 'Jones',
    'Residence': [{'Place': 'Z', 'Age': 20}]
}
]
```

The SQL I would use would be something like this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT **Residence Object**)
FROM items
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

How would I do this in `pandas`, so that I don't get an `unhashable type` error when trying to get the distinct array elements?

Comment: You only need to change the mapping function, it's almost exactly the same thing as your last question.

Answer (score 1):

Barring anything else, I don't think Pandas would give you any real benefit here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for e in items:
    d[(e['FirstName'], e['LastName'])].append(e['Residence'])
items = [{'FirstName': k[0], 'LastName': k[1], 'Residence': v} for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution from `pandas`

```
#df=pd.DataFrame(items)
df.groupby(['FirstName','LastName']).Residence.\
    apply(lambda x : x.sum()).\
       apply(lambda x : [dict(y) for y in set(tuple(t.items()) for t in x)]).\
         reset_index().to_dict('r')
Out[104]: 
[{'FirstName': 'Bob',
  'LastName': 'Jones',
  'Residence': [{'Age': 20, 'Place': 'Z'}]},
 {'FirstName': 'David',
  'LastName': 'Smith',
  'Residence': [{'Age': 20, 'Place': 'Z'},
   {'Age': 23, 'Place': 'Y'},
   {'Age': 22, 'Place': 'X'}]}]
```

Comment: OMG, this solution serves more as a testament to your Pandas proficiency, than to Pandas's suitability to this problem, IMHO :-)

Comment: You can change `apply(lambda x: x.sum())` for `apply(sum)` only :)